# 301 redirect from home page - Update domain in google search console

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, google-search, google-search-console

I recently changed my site's domain and would like to update it in search console. I have the ownership of both domains verified in search console and I set the first domain (the old one) to redirect with 301 to the second domain (the new one)

However when I check within search console for address change, I get the error:

Validation failed
One or more mandatory tests have not been passed. Unable to proceed with the request.

with in red

301 redirect from home page
Failed to fetch the page.

Basically I have to ensure that the ownership of the pet-boxoffice.com domain (which currently points to [theanimalshop.it](https://theanimalshop.it/) with a 301 redirect) is transferred to the [theanimalshop.it](https://theanimalshop.it/) website

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGZJ.png)

I tried to change the redirect from https to http and vice versa but the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and I tried **EVERYTHING**! I kept only **http/1.1**, tried redirecting just to http, to https, redirecting via HTML... I tried everything!!

But unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the problem.

---

However, there is a way to work around this...

1º Set up the 301 permanent redirect on the old site.

2º Clear the Google Cache [(Google Console)](https://search.google.com/search-console/removals):

[image]

It's not a perfect solution, but in the next Crawl, it will check the redirect!